# Passing iterative data from button to modal in razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, bootstrap-modal

I have a razor view page where I loop through my list and render it on a table row by row. At each row, there is a button to send the informations stored in the spesific row via mail but the button is not triggering mail sending operation by itself. It opens a modal and asks user to either continue the process or not. After that, the button inside the modal is going to trigger the javascript method of mail sending process. Here is my loop;

```
@foreach (var file in Model.ExcelLogListPaged)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="">@file.ID</td>
                        <td>@file.UploadedDate</td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="button"  data-toggle ="modal" data-target="#warningModal" id="sendMailButton_@file.ID">Send Mail</button></td>
                    </tr>
                }
```

And here is my modal;

```
div id="warningModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="z-index:9999;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure?</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Are you sure to send the mail manually?</p>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As I mentioned, I have a javascript method `SendMail()` which is responsible for sending mail. I want to trigger it via the modal's button that is why I need to assign it via `onclick`attribute. However, this method needs a parameter and this parameter should be passed via the modal's caller button. To be more spesific, I want to pass the data `@file.ID` from the loop to my modal and then use it to assign to `onclick` attribute of modal's submit button like `SendMail(@file.ID)`. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

add fileid attribute to button in the loop, and a any css class say "file"

```
@foreach (var file in Model.ExcelLogListPaged)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td class="">@file.ID</td>
                    <td>@file.UploadedDate</td>
                    <td><button fileid="@file.ID" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="button"  data-toggle 
        ="modal" class="file" data-target="#warningModal" id="sendMailButton_@file.ID">Send Mail</button></td>
                </tr>
            }
```

then add hidden field in modal popup

```
     div id="warningModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="z-index:9999;">
<div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure?</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Are you sure to send the mail manually?</p>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- 
             dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data- 
             dismiss="modal">Send</button>
              <input type="hidden" id="hdnselectedfield" /> 
           </div>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

add below script

```
<script>
 $(".file").on("click",function(){
    $("#hdnselectedfield").val($(this).val()))
  })

 </script>
```

you will get the fileid in hidden field which you can send thorugh

```
   SendMail($("#hdnselectedfield").val())
```